# Javascript write DOM not working out of function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty new to javascript and I can't get this to run.

After pressing the equal button it runs the function calc() which should write the calculator result onto the display but it just don't work... But if I run the `calc()` from developer console it runs perfectly so I guess there is something wrong with scoping whatsoever. Maybe you guys have an idea :)?

Please forgive me missing error handling as I am doing basic stuff first.

```js
/**
 * core
 */
var display = null;
var input = null;

var latestNumber = null;
var result = null;
var displayNumber = null;
var operator = null;

function setOperator(operatorValue) {

    if (displayNumber === null && operator === null){
        displayNumber = readInput();
        writeOutput(displayNumber + " " + String(operatorValue));
        clearInput();

    } else if (displayNumber !== null && operator !== null){
        writeOutput( displayNumber + " " + String(operatorValue));
    }

    operator = String(operatorValue);


}

function addDigit(digit){
    let oldValue = readInput();

    if(Number.isNaN(oldValue)){
        oldValue = "";
    }

    let newInputValue = String(oldValue) + String(digit); //Parse numbers to string

    writeInput(newInputValue);
}

function calc (firstNumber, op, secondNumber){

    switch (op) {
        case "+":
            result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
            break;

        case "-":
            result = firstNumber - secondNumber;
            break;

        case "*":
            result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
            break;

        case "/":
            if (secondNumber === 0) {
                window.alert("Error: Division by zero");
            }
            else {
                result = firstNumber / secondNumber;
            }
            break;
    }

    operator = null;
    latestNumber = null;
    displayNumber = null;

    writeInput(result);
}

/**
 * UI
 */


window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    //Initialize number Buttons
    (function () {
        const numbers = document.getElementsByClassName("number");

        for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
            numbers[i].addEventListener('click', () => addDigit(numbers[i].value));
        }
    })();

    //Initialize operation Buttons
    (function () {
        const operators = document.getElementsByClassName("operator");
        for (let i = 0; i < operators.length; ++i) {
            operators[i].addEventListener('click', () => setOperator (operators[i].value));
        }
    })();

    //Initialize calc button
    (function () {
        const equalButton = document.getElementById("key-=");
        equalButton.addEventListener('click', ()=> calc (displayNumber, operator, readInput()));
    })();

    //Initialize clear button
    (function () {
        const commands = document.getElementsByClassName("command");
        for (let i = 0; i < commands.length; ++i) {
            commands[i].addEventListener('click', ()=> clearAll ());
        }
    })();

    //Initialize Display
    display = (function (){
        return document.getElementById("output");
    })();
    input = (function () {
        return document.getElementById("input");
    })();
    writeOutput("Welcome");

});

//Function to read from input
function readInput () {
    return parseFloat(input.value);
}

//Function to write to input
function writeInput (value) {
    input.value = value;
}

//Function to write to output
function writeOutput (string) {
    display.value = string;
}

//Function to clear input
function clearInput () {
    input.value = "";
}

//Function to clear output
function clearOutput () {
    display.value = "";
}

//Function to clear display
function clearAll (){
    result = null;
    lastNumber = null;
    displayNumber = null;
    operator = null;

    clearInput();
    clearOutput();
}
```

```css
/* reset */
*  {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

html {
 font-size: 1vw;
}

html, body {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}


/* document */
body {
 font-family: "URW Gothic L", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
 /* Background source:
  * http://www.texturex.com/Leather-Textures/black+leather+texture+large+close+up+grain+material+dark+fabric+stock+photo.jpg.php
  * Free offered by Free Leather Textures */
 background: url('../../../media/black-leather-texture.jpg');
}

.display {
 border: 0.2rem solid gray;
 border-radius: 0.5rem;
 background: black;
 padding: 0.5rem;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
}
.display > output {
 display: block;
 height: 1.5rem;
 margin: 0;
 color: aqua;
}

form {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0.5rem;
}

fieldset {
 border: none;
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 0;
}
fieldset > button {
 width: 20%;
 margin: 3.3%;
 padding: 2vw;
}
fieldset > button:nth-child(4n) {
 margin-right: 0;
}
fieldset > button:nth-child(4n+1) {
 margin-left: 0;
}

button {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem black;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 0.5rem;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin: 0;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
}
output {
 font-size: 1rem;
}


button.number, button.command {
 background: white;
}
button.number:active, button.command:active {
 background: rgb(230, 230, 230);
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0.5rem black;
}
button.operator {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem rgb(80,80, 80);
 background: black;
 color: white;
}
button.operator:active {
 background: rgb(60, 60, 60);
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0.5rem black;
}

#key-c {
 background: red;
 color: white;
}
#key-c:active {
 background: darkred;
}
button:focus {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset class="display">
    <output name="output" id="output" class="output"></output>
    <output name="input" id="input" class="input"></output>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <button type="button" name="key-0" id="key-0" class="number" value="0">0</button>
    <button type="button" name="key-1" id="key-1" class="number" value="1">1</button>
    <button type="button" name="key-2" id="key-2" class="number" value="2">2</button>
    <button type="button" name="key-+" id="key-+" value="+" class="operator">&plus;</button>

    <button type="button" name="key-3" id="key-3" class="number" value="3">3</button>
    <button type="button" name="key-4" id="key-4" class="number" value="4">4</button>
    <button type="button" name="key-5" id="key-5" class="number" value="5">5</button>
    <button type="button" name="key--" id="key--" value="-" class="operator">&minus;</button>

    <button type="button" name="key-6" id="key-6" class="number" value="6">6</button>
    <button type="button" name="key-7" id="key-7" class="number" value="7">7</button>
    <button type="button" name="key-8" id="key-8" class="number" value="8">8</button>
    <button type="button" name="key-*" id="key-*" value="*" class="operator">&lowast;</button>

    <button type="button" name="key-9" id="key-9" class="number" value="9">9</button>
    <button type="button" name="key-c" id="key-c" class="command">C</button>
    <button type="button" name="key-=" id="key-=" class="command">&equals;</button>
    <button type="button" name="key-/" id="key-/" value="/" class="operator">&divide;</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the "Clear" and the "Equals" buttons are sharing the same class.

So, when you call the equals function it also triggers this code:

```
(function () {
    const commands = document.getElementsByClassName("command");
    for (let i = 0; i < commands.length; ++i) {
        commands[i].addEventListener('click', ()=> clearAll ());
    }
})();
```

You are printing the result and then clearing the field.

Try changing the class on the equals button and it will work.

```
        <button type="button" name="key-c" id="key-c" class="command">C</button>
        <button type="button" name="key-=" id="key-=" class="equals">&equals;</button>
```

Comment: Thanks this was it. I initially had a switch statement for command buttons but decided to add event listeners seperately due to better understanding. Seems like I forgot to delete the old one.

Comment: Happy to help. Please mark the question as answered.